# How to know that my array contains dictionary or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I have an array like this

```
   ( {
    GPSOdometerReading = "11843.6";
    "_id" =         {
        "$oid" = 5656e7175201edbb16a483f4;
    };
    acc = 0;
    )
```

So how to know that my array contains the dictionary or not?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to enumurate over array & check class of each object like below

```
BOOL isContainsDict = NO;
for (id value in Array){
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        isContainsDict = YES;
        break; // end since you only want to know if the array contains an instance of dictionary. if it does no need to continue the loop just break and perform the process
      }
}
```

Comment: Good answer and very short

Comment: `isContainsDict` should be initialised.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use this code:

```
-(BOOL)arrayContainDictionary
{
     for(int i=0; i<[array count];i++){
         if([array[i] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary Dictionary]]){
             return YES;
         }
     }
     return NO;
}
```

Comment: This will return NO if first object is not NSDictionary without checking further, return NO should be outside the forloop.